# How to toggle Cell value based on current Time, Day and a condition in google sheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm fairly new to google sheets, I wanted to do something like this:

```
IF ( (current time is within 8am - 2pm) AND (day is NOT (sunday OR saturday) ) 
THEN => cell value = "OPEN"
ELSE => cell value = "CLOSED"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(AND(HOUR(NOW())>=8, HOUR(NOW())<=14, WEEKDAY(NOW(),2)<6), "OPEN", "CLOSED")
```

- [NOW()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092981) – Returns the current date and time as a date value.
- [HOUR()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093045) - Returns the hour component of a specific time, in numeric format.
- [WEEKDAY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985) – Returns a number representing the day of the week of the date provided. By specifying the `2`, the values of Saturday & Sunday are 6 & 7, so it makes the logic easier.
- [AND()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301) - The AND function returns true if all of the provided arguments are logically true, and false if any of the provided arguments are logically false.
- [IF()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) – Returns one value if a logical expression is `TRUE` and another if it is `FALSE`.

Comment: Hey thanks a tonne, it seems so easy when I look at your answer :) also, if I want 8:15 am instead of 8am, it'll be 8.25 right?